# Collection view cell Shown in center ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

Collection view are shown in the center aligned.
I am creating 3 column and multiple rows. in a case, if one of the cell height becomes greater then the other cell shown in the center of the long cell. I want it to be the top left.
Please let me know if there is any solution for this issue

Comment: Show your code and screenshot

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do (any screenshot/drawing?) but this smells like using a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.